# pass a tuple as parameter to sql query

Tags: python, sql, jupyter-notebook, databricks

```
at_lst = ['131','132','133']

at_tup = (*at_lst,)
 
print(at_tup)
('131','132','133')
```

In my sql query, i am trying to pass this on a parameter, however, it doesn't work.

```
%%sql
select * from main.schema.tbl
where code IN ( '{{ at_tup }}' )
```

This return no result.

However, when I pass the actual tuple, I get the desired results:

```
select * from main.schema.tbl
where code IN ('131','132','133')
```

How do I pass a tuple as a paramter the sql query without using the `execute` cursor object method?

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
at_tup = (*at_lst,)
query = f"""
select * from main.schema.tbl
where code IN {at_tup}
"""
```

after that pass the `query` to `execute`